# How can calculate time from particular date/time instead current time in delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am using delayed job in rails. Now,

I am able to use run_at 1.minutes.from_now. and it is working fine. but as per my requirement time should be calculate from specific time like start_time in below code.

In controller level

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue DeviceJob.new(msg), :run_at => msg.start_time
```

In model level

```
class DeviceJob < Struct.new(:msg)
  def perform
    # something code
  end
end
```

but in that case run_at will add in delayed job but on that time it will not process.
I don't have any other method in delayed job instead run_at.

I am using MongoDB(Nosql database)

Comment: what is msg.start_time class? check it by msg.start_time.class

Comment: ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

Comment: what you mean that delayed job isn't processing job from `msg.start_time` provided in run_at option?

Comment: yes. if i check by Delayed::Job.all it will show job list. but for run_at will not process for specified time.